# How To Combine <> and X variable in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on excel VBA and I want all rows that does not equal to my cell value/reference (Cell E5) to be deleted but what is happening right, it deletes all rows in that sheet.

```
Sub DeleteNotEqualTo()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    x = Range("E5").Value

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Conso")
    
    ws.Range("B8:Z5000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<> & x"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    ws.Range("B9:Z5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
          
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    On Error Resume Next 'Clear Filter
    
    ws.ShowAllData
        
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Format all code as code.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in your workbook is changing this line:

```
ws.Range("B8:Z5000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<> & x"
```

to:

```
ws.Range("B8:Z5000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>*" & x & "*"
```

---

The presence of `*` wildcard changes the criteria from an exact match to a *partial* match. (This shouldn't have been necessary, but specifying an exact match didn't filter the range correctly for reasons I'm unsure of.)

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DeleteNotEqualTo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Conso")
    
    Dim x As Variant
    x = Range("E5").Value
    
    ws.Range("B8:Z5000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>*" & x & "*"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Range("B9:Z5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    On Error Resume Next 'Clear Filter
    ws.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi chillin, thank you for answering my question. I changed it but it is still the same.

Comment: @Poch sorry that it didn't work for you, what's the type of the value in cell `E5`? For example, is it a date, string, number, text?

Comment: The value is "Sep 2020"

Comment: @Poch, see the edit, I think you need `CDbl(x)` for dates, so not just `x`.

Comment: Can I share my template to you?

Comment: @Poch, sure, you can upload to it something like Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, etc -- and then paste a link in your question

Comment: Good day! Here is the link below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KGw_2Yv5pPlxhXb3RBgMcO6rzlDSi8x1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is not password protected. Just hit "OK" if it asks for a password.

Comment: Good day! Sorry I don't know what happened but I can't download the file anymore. Can you post here the updated VBA script? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: @Poch, see answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're setting the reference value in cell E5 (row 5) and starting from row 8 ("B8:Z5000") you crosscheck if for each record field 11 corresponds to that specific value.

I don't recommend this approach because:

1. when manipulating spreadsheets, you shouldn't use the auto filter. The auto filter is rather designed for visibility when you look at a spreadsheet - not for a programmatic approach. You should be aware that, even if data is filtered out of the visible range, if you'd loop through the records, the program would still take the non visible records into consideration.
2. by setting a static range, you are always going to be limited by the number of rows you set. You can easily use a dynamic range instead, like that your script will always crosscheck all rows that are not empty.

   ```
   Option Explicit
   'always recommend to use this option, it forces you to
   'declare the type of every single variable

   Sub DeleteNotEqualTo()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Conso")
   Dim x As String 'declaring string variable, you may have to adapt
   'x = Range("E5").Value you could also with the cells object, check next line
   x = ws.Cells(5, 5).Value '5,5 = row 5, column 5

   'now comes the loop
   'you have to declare a so called iterator variable to loop, in this case "i"
   'the iterator drives the loop through the records
   'you also need a variable that determines the last row to be checked
   'in this case you define this by checking the so called "UsedRange"
   'the "UsedRange" counts from the first row that contains to the last
   'check out the indicated link for more info regarding finding the last row

   Dim i As Integer 'iterator variable
   Dim lrow As Integer 'variable for the last row
   lrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 4 'assuming that row 5 is the first to contain a value

   'now loop through the records
   'here I'm assuming field 11 of your auto filter correspond to column 11 in the sheet
   'important sidenote: as you're deleting rows, you have to loop bottom up
   'if you loop top to bottom, the loop may skip rows that shift up
   For i = lrow To 8 Step -1 'assuming that the first row to be checked is row 8
       If ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = x Then
           ws.Cells(i, 11).EntireRow.Delete
       End If
   Next i

   End Sub
   ```

Here's a link with more info regarding finding the last row in a spreadsheet. Very helpful with dynamic ranges:

https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/